# Can you invoke a control rather than launch an app for coded ui tests?

Tags: mstest, coded-ui-tests

I have code such that:

```
[CodedUITest]
public class CodedUITest1
{

[TestMethod]
public void CodedUITestMethod1( )
{
  using(var dlg = new MyWinForm( ))
  {
    dlg.Show();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    this.UIMap.AssertMethod1( );
    this.UIMap.RecordedMethod1( );
    this.UIMap.AssertMethod2( );
   }

  }
}
```

The code was running fine when I manually launched the app(before invoking the test) without the using clause to directly create the control.

I'd like to just use a reference to create an instance of the control and go from there instead of relying on trying to determine a path to the executable and opening it. The app just gets stuck with a `ContextSwitchDeadlock`.

Is there a way to do coded-Ui tests without doing a process launch? (using the reference and creating the control in the test code) or is there something wrong with the way I'm trying to do it?

Comment: Then after clicking OK to the Context Switch Deadlock and clicking play again in VS2010 ultimate... I get a UITestControlNotFoundException

Comment: I know this is 5 years ago but did you ever manage to get this working? I'm attempting to do the same thing and running into the same issues?

Comment: I don't believe I did.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible if you invoke the coded ui test portions (this.UIMap...) on a separate thread. But the way you have it now, they are both on the same thread, so you are going to get deadlocked.